# Using msdelta.dll with rundll32 from command promp?

Tags: patch

I'd like to use the CreateDelta function in msdelta.dll via rundll32.

Is this possible? I cannot figure out the proper syntax.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that this question would be better asked on SU.

Answer (score 1):

No. `rundll32` requires a very specific function signature (`void CALLBACK EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)`).

The [`CreateDelta` signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417345.aspx#createdeltaaw) is very different:

```
BOOL  WINAPI  CreateDeltaW(
           DELTA_FILE_TYPE  FileTypeSet,
           DELTA_FLAG_TYPE  SetFlags,
           DELTA_FLAG_TYPE  ResetFlags,
           LPCWSTR          lpSourceName,
           LPCWSTR          lpTargetName,
           LPCWSTR          lpSourceOptionsName,
           LPCWSTR          lpTargetOptionsName,
           DELTA_INPUT      GlobalOptions,
    const  FILETIME        *lpTargetFileTime,
           ALG_ID           HashAlgId,
           LPCWSTR          lpDeltaName
    );
```

As these two do not match, they cannot be used together.

See also:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/09/10208136.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx